# Simple enough subsequences of the sequence $n^2+1$ and prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Is it reasonable to expect that some simple enough subsequences of the sequence $n^2+1$ will contain more primes (on average) than the sequence $n^2+1$ itself?

For example, we could define $a(n)=n^2+1$ and $b(n)=n!$ and study behavior of the subsequence $c(n)=a(b(n))=(n!)^2+1$, or $a(n)=n^2+1$ and $b(n)=n^2$ and study $c(n)=a(b(n))=n^4+1$.

> Has anything been done in this direction? What are the known results?

Computational efforts are welcomed.

Comment: It's not even known whether $n^2+1$ has infinitely many primes. Thus whether a subsequence has infinitely many...

Comment: @Robert I know, the question is not about are there an infinite number of primes in some of those subsequences or in the sequence $n^2+1$.

Comment: What do you get when "reasonable" means compatible with the random model for the primes ? ($X_n = 1_{n \text{ is prime}}$ is a sequence of independent random variables with $P[X_n=1] = \frac{1}{\log n}$)

Comment: @reuns I cannot stand "random models for primes", Primes are not random at all.

Comment: You can take a look at the Bateman-Horn conjecture as a start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman%E2%80%93Horn_conjecture

Comment: The random model for the primes is more or less the only way we know to make some close-to-the-truth conjectures on the density of primes in polynomial progressions. It is also the building block of things like [Cramer's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_conjecture#Heuristic_justification) on the prime gap.

Comment: @reuns That could also be the reason why all or almost all such conjectures are still unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that $n^2+1$ represents infinite primes (Landau's conjecture), the density of primes in the subsequence given by values of $n$ such that

$$ n\not\in\{2,3\}\pmod{5}, \quad n\not\in\{5,8\}\pmod{13}$$
is greater, since $-1$ is a quadratic residue both in $\mathbb{F}_5$ and in $\mathbb{F}_{13}$.  Indeed, one gets a proof of Landau's conjecture if he/she manages to prove that an extension of such sieve leaves out an infinite number of elements.